# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii' при авторизации API

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, python-3.6, test-automation

Версия Python 3.6
Добрый день. Пытаюсь интегрировать TestComplete с TestRail, чтобы после отработки скрипта автоматически проставлялся статус кейса в TestRail.
Написал такой код:

```
testrail_user_email = os.environ.get('user_email')
testrail_user_password = os.environ.get('user_password')
testrail_auth = (user_email, user_password)

def SendStatus():
    get_cases_url = 'Тут был УРЛ'
    data = {'status_id': 1, 'comment': 'Passed'}
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    response = requests.post(url=get_cases_url, auth=testrail_auth, data=payload)
```

Но скрипт выдает ошибку - `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii'`
Ругается на аутентификацию. Из интернета узнал, что метод 'isascii' используется с версии 3.7, но библиотека Request для 3.6
Пробовал со скриптами самого TestRail, которые они предоставляют. Та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Добавьте полный текст ошибки вместе с трэйсбэком. По трэйсбэку нужно смотреть, в каком месте вылетает ошибка, смотреть в какой версии были изменения в requests в этом месте, и закреплять (устанавливать) версию requests в которой еще не было этих изменений.

Comment: @insolor А то и может оказаться, что эту ошибку вообще не `requests` выдаёт, а какая-то другая библиотека

Comment: @insolor У меня проблема в том, что в работе я использую TestComplete и его IDE  в связке с Python. Там есть отчет об ошибках, но он не детализирован. Запустить в PyCharm  не могу, так как там не установлена библиотека requests, а на рабочем компе я не могу ее установить из-за политики.

Comment: Не знаю что за "его IDE", но там по идее можно создать пустой скрипт, в нем тупо вызвать `requests.post()` по любому адресу (даже не существующему) с любыми данными, если проблема в requests, то упадет с полным трэйсбэком.

Comment: @insolor Да, дело в этой библиотеке. Скрипт останавливается на строке - ```response = requests.post(url=get_cases_url, auth=testrail_auth, data=payload)```. Проверил саму библиотеку. Нигде там не нашел атрибута isascii

Comment: @insolor ```Python runtime error.

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isascii'```

Comment: Это только одна строка без трэйсбэка, этого не достаточно

Comment: Проверьте, что установлен requests версии не выше [2.27.1](https://pypi.org/project/requests/2.27.1/) - это последняя версия, в которой есть поддержка Python 3.6

Comment: @insolor У меня 2.24.0

Comment: Тогда берете grep и в директории с установленными модулями делаете `grep -r "\.isascii("`

Comment: @insolor Запустил скрипт в питоновском файле, через командную строку. Данная ошибка не появилась. Вернулась ошибка авторизации, но это уже совсем другое.

Comment: Значит из IDE у вас другое окружение питона запускается, чем из командной строки

Comment: @insolor Проблему частично решил. Добавил в PyCharm необходимые библиотеки, скрипт норм отработал. Указал путь в переменных средах на библиотеку в PyCharm и использовал данный путь в TestComplete. Скрипт также нормально отработал. Видимо в библиотеках Пайтона в Local какой-то конфликт. Буду разбираться, а пока так оставлю.